# Sum cells in one column, if values match criteria from two separate columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please I need some help as I'm having trouble getting this to work. Please see the image below. The result I want is the value in cell B21 for the entire table in the picture. Cell A21 contains one piece of the criteria for the formula. I need to sum the values in column H if the value in column F matches A21 and has the same value in column C or E. For example, the Proj# is the same for cells E2 and E3, and since F2 matches A21, the formula in theory will sum H2 and H3. The result would be 9. I'd prefer a faster processing formula than an array or query

[image: Image of Spreadsheet]

Comment: Thank you for adding the image Scott.

Comment: By that same logic it should pickup H4 and H5 they are the same in C and E and one of F matches A21.  Why only H2 and H3?

Comment: You are correct. My example was just to clarify 1 calculation. I would like it to sum H4 and H5 along with H2 and H3, but not H6 - H9 etc.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet, so we do not need to recreate the data.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r5ylCQ_RJzjfgs0FXAkPzy7blqs3y63H3GE9w-yzOyI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Filter and Match:

```
=sum(filter(H2:H16,isnumber(MATCH(E2:E16,filter(E2:E16,F2:F16=A21),0))+ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:C16,filter(C2:C16,F2:F16=A21),0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Scott! This is a great help!

Answer (score 0):

shorter:

```
=SUM(FILTER(H:H, REGEXMATCH(E:E&C:C, JOIN("|", FILTER(E:E&C:C, F:F=A21)))))
```

[image]

Comment: I may understand incorrectly but is not this C and E match?  The op asked for C or E match.  Again I may misunderstand the functionality of your formula.